# f3read - what is the difference between corrupted, changed and overwritten sectors?

Tags: usb, flash-memory, badblocks

I'm using `f3` to test hundreds of USB flash memory sticks for errors.

Here's an example output from a faulty drive. First writing test files with `f3write`:

```
Free space: 3.74 GB
Creating file 1.h2w ... OK!
Creating file 2.h2w ... OK!
Creating file 3.h2w ... OK!
Creating file 4.h2w ... OK!
Free space: 0.00 Byte
Average writing speed: 2.22 MB/s
```

Then reading back with `f3read`:

```
                  SECTORS      ok/corrupted/changed/overwritten
Validating file 1.h2w ... 2030944/        0/      0/  66208
Validating file 2.h2w ... 2032136/        0/      0/  65016
Validating file 3.h2w ... 2031920/        0/      0/  65232
Validating file 4.h2w ... 1509112/        0/      0/  48376

  Data OK: 3.63 GB (7604112 sectors)
Data LOST: 119.55 MB (244832 sectors)
               Corrupted: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
        Slightly changed: 0.00 Byte (0 sectors)
             Overwritten: 119.55 MB (244832 sectors)
Average reading speed: 3.23 MB/s
```

Typically if a USB drive contains errors, they come up in the corrupted column. Recently I've got drives that report errors in the "overwritten" column. I wonder what is the difference between the three.

I've also noticed that `badblocks` utility also reports errors in three columns, I wonder if it's the same scheme? EDIT: not it's not - [How to interpret badblocks output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65349/how-to-interpret-badblocks-output#65351)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `f3` documentation](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3/blob/master/doc/usage.rst) says:

> When `f3read` reads a sector (i.e. 512 bytes, the unit of communication with the card), `f3read` can check if the sector was correctly written by `f3write`, and figure out in which file the sector should be and in which position in that file the sector should be. Thus, if a sector is well formed, or with a few bits flipped, but read in an unexpected position, `f3read` counts it as overwritten. Slightly changed sectors, are sectors at right position with a fews bits flipped.

The three types of errors mean:

- changed: the sector was written by `f3write`, and read in the expected position, with some changes (less than the “tolerance”, which allows for [two errors](https://github.com/AltraMayor/f3/blob/master/f3read.c#L112));
- overwritten: the sector read contains data written by `f3write` to another sector, possibly with some changes (within the tolerance);
- corrupted: the sector doesn’t match data written by `f3write` (the changes exceed the tolerance).

All three are bad news, but of different kinds. Overwritten sectors indicate that the drive is lying about its capacity and is wrapping writes.

Comment: I'm getting a very few, variable overwritten sectors, I can't seem to make sense of it. Card looks, feels, and speedtests very real:
SECTORS      ok/corrupted/changed/overwritten
Validating file 1.h2w ... 2097088/        0/      0/     64
Validating file 2.h2w ... 2096960/        0/      0/    192
Validating file 3.h2w ... 2097088/        0/      0/     64

Oddly had a non2^X further down (31). Not a full test as this card is 256GB, I just unwrapped it, currently making a full test. Test on macos, Back to you in about 3h with a full test, which should be the same... Any thoughts?